# Webob / Pyramid query string parameters out of order upon receipt

Tags: python, api, parameters, query-string, pyramid

I am running Pyramid as my API server. Recently we started getting query string parameters out of order when handed to the RESTful API server. For example, a GET to `/v1/finishedGoodRequests?exact=true&id=39&join=OR&exact=false&name=39`
is logged by the RESTful api module upon **init** as request.url:

```
v1/finishedGoodRequests?join=OR&name=39&exact=true&exact=false&id=39
```

with request.query_string: join=OR&name=39&exact=true&exact=false&id=39

I process the query params in order to qualify the search, in this case id exactly 39 or 39 anywhere in the name. What kind of possible server setting or bug could have crept in to the server code to cause such a thing? It is still a MultiDict...

Comment: Any chance you can reproduce it outside of your app?

Answer (score 0):

As a simple example, this works fine for me, and the MultiDict has always preserved the order and so I suspect something is getting rewritten by something you're using in your stack.

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.view import view_config
from waitress import serve

@view_config(renderer='json')
def view(request):
    return list(request.GET.items())

config = Configurator()
config.scan(__name__)
app = config.make_wsgi_app()

serve(app, listen='127.0.0.1:8080')

$ curl http://localhost:8080\?join=OR\&name=39\&exact=true\&exact=false\&id=39
[["join", "OR"], ["name", "39"], ["exact", "true"], ["exact", "false"], ["id", "39"]]
```

Depending on which WSGI server you are using, often you can view environ vars to see the original url which may be handy. Waitress does not, so instead just put something high up in the pipeline (wsgi middleware) that can log out the `environ['QUERY_STRING']` and see if it doesn't match somewhere lower down in your stack.